# WiFi Game Controller Protocol

Tags: android, iphone, controllers

I'm wanting to use mobile devices to control a game.  I'd like to use an industry standard protocol for wifi game controllers rather than roll my own, but have been unable to find any standard.

Does there exist any industry standard wifi game controller protocol?  Is there some unofficial protocol many implement, preferably with quality Android/iPhone client implementations available?

Comment: NVIDIA Shield controllers are WiFi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there is no such standard, because there are no WiFi game controllers. All the wireless game controllers I checked use either Bluetooth or some proprietary wireless data transmission.

This makes sense as WiFi typically uses more power than Bluetooth and is harder to set up. A wireless network might not even be available on location.

That being said, there exist [some apps for Android](https://www.google.com/#q=android+as+gamepad) as well as [for the iPhone](https://www.google.com/#q=iphone+as+gamepad) just for that purpose. Maybe you could contact the authors for how they work.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  I'm avoiding bluetooth because the project utilizes Adruino and the Bluetooth components are extra.  I tried contacting the authors of 3 promising applications 2 months ago to no avail.  Guess I'll just have to roll my own.  Thanks for your input.